# Ruby on rails with React Frontend(Displaying associated data)

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I been trying show association between users and posts tables in rails. My problem is that when a user logs in, he/she should be able to see all of their own posts in my react frontend. However, my frontend request is only able to fetch first record that is related to my current user.
This is where I send a fetch request to my backend to get the posts that are related to the user's id.

```
export default function Profile({currentUser}){

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

     useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`/posts/${currentUser.id}`)
        .then((r) =>{
          if(r.ok){
              r.json().then((posts)=>setPosts(posts))
          }
      })
    }, [])
```

And this is my how my route looks like

```
 get '/posts/:id', to: "posts#show"
```

Lastly, this is where my backend fetches blog posts that are related to the logged in user.

```
  def show
     posts = Post.find_by(id:params[:id])
     render json: posts, include: :user
  end
```

I know the fact that find_by method only fetches the first record that meets the condition.
I also tried using `user.Post.all` to fetch the records. Any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your request will return the `Post` with the `:id` of your `currentUser`. I think that's not what you want... :)

I guess you want something like:

```
def show
   posts = User.find(params[:id]).posts # Hint: find_by(id: id) == find(id)
   ...
end
```

Comment: That will return the Posts but the whole setup is not correct. It should be an Index action and the current user should be already in scope from the Back-End.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the routes, the controller, and the request in a weird way.

**Problems**

I assume the controller you shared is the Posts Controller, that means you need the **Index** action, not the Show action. The **Show** action is used when you want to render a single Post.

You pass the `currentUser.id` to the backend as `posts/:id`. I'm afraid that's not right as the `posts/:id` refers to a Post id not a User id. Apart from that, your Backend should be already aware of the User as it is logged in.

Your authorization gem should have a way to access the current User. For example, the devise gem exposes has a method called `current_user` to all the controllers.

**Solution**

That means your route should be `get '/posts', to: "posts#index"`

Your controller should be

```
  def index
     posts = current_user.posts # current_user or your way to access the user
     render json: posts, include: :user
  end
```

Your React front-end should be

```
export default function Profile({currentUser}){

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

     useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`/posts`)
        .then((r) =>{
          if(r.ok){
              r.json().then((posts)=>setPosts(posts))
          }
      })
    }, [])
```